# Table View sections for fetchedResultsController objects

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to index my tableView data, ordering the names of the people listed by its name initials. I've seen lots of tutorials about doing so with genericall non-persistent data, but none with Core Data and making use of fetchedResultsController option (for iCloud auto-sync).

Now my code is as follows (for clarity purposes, I transcribe only question-related parts):

```
//The two arrays to populate from Core Data, used later to populate the table
var alumnosDictionaryArray = [String:[String]]()
var titulosSeccionArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //Obtain data from Core Data    
    updateFetchedResultsController()

    //Populate the arrays with this data
    populateArrays()


func updateFetchedResultsController() {
    guard let context = container?.viewContext else { return }
    
    context.performAndWait {
        
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombre", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<Alumno>(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch {
            print("Error obtaining data: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func populateArrays() {
    
    if let objects = fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects {
        
        for alumno in objects {
            let inicial = String(alumno.nombre?.prefix(1) ?? "")
            
            if var values = alumnosDictionaryArray[inicial] {
                values.append(alumno.nombre!)
                alumnosDictionaryArray[inicial] = values
            } else {
                alumnosDictionaryArray[inicial] = [alumno.nombre!]
            }
        }
        
        titulosSeccionArray = [String](alumnosDictionaryArray.keys)
        titulosSeccionArray = titulosSeccionArray.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})
    }
}
```

This part seems to work ok, as the arrays are filled correctly, as I have checked with printing statements.

Later, for table data:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    
    return titulosSeccionArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let inicial = titulosSeccionArray[section]
    if let values = alumnosDictionaryArray[inicial] {
        return values.count
    }
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! AlumnoCell
    
    if self.validateIndexPath(indexPath) {
        
        let object = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath)
        let inicial = titulosSeccionArray[indexPath.section]
       
        if let values = alumnosDictionaryArray[inicial] {
            
            cell.nombreField.text = values[indexPath.section]
            cell.especialidadField.text = object?.especialidadRelacionada?.nombre
            cell.cursoField.text = object?.cursoRelacionado?.nivel
            cell.tutorField.text = object?.tutorRelacionado?.nombre
        }
    } else {
        print("Error from indexPath")
    }
  
    return cell
}

//To validate indexPath
func validateIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if let sections = self.fetchedResultsController?.sections,
       indexPath.section < sections.count {
        if indexPath.row < sections[indexPath.section].numberOfObjects {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    
    return titulosSeccionArray[section]
}
```

I get a more-or-less complete table with the correct sections, title of sections (initials), and number of rows for each, but it seems that only firs row works, as the rest of data are empty and throw an error when selecting any: 'no section at index 1'. In fact, I get many "Error from indexPath" messages on the console before exception throwing...

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: I believe this would be easier if you used the section ability built into NSFetchedResultsController instead of trying to do it with your own arrays.  When I have done this, I've put a "section" field into my objects and then used that as the section keypath while fetching.  That way, the table view can be filled directly from the results.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me a more detailed example. I'm beginning with swift and not have clear your idea.

Answer (score 0):

For `Alumno` entity add 1 more column of `nombreFirstChar`.
Then use something like this to save this variable in database:

```
alumno.nombreFirstChar = nombre.firstCharacter()
```

Here `firstCharacter` helper method will be like this:

```
func firstCharacter() -> String {
    var firstCharacter = self.first ?? "#"
    
    if (!(firstCharacter >= "a" && firstCharacter <= "z") && !(firstCharacter >= "A" && firstCharacter <= "Z") ) {
        firstCharacter = "#"
    }
    return String(firstCharacter).capitalized
}
```

Now in your fetchedResultsController,replace this line

```
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<Alumno>(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

with

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "nombreFirstChar", ascending: true)]
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["nombreFirstChar"]
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<Alumno>(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nombreFirstChar, cacheName: nil)
```

Then in table view delegate apis, you can use fetchedResultsController like this:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
}

func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    
    guard let fetchedResultsSections: [NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo] = channelFetchedResultsController.sections else {return nil}
    
    return fetchedResultsSections!.map{String($0.name)}
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    guard var fetchedResultsSections: [NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo] = fetchedResultsController.sections else {return nil}
    return fetchedResultsSections[section].name
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    guard var sections:[NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo] = fetchedResultsController.sections, let section = sections[section] else {
        return 0
    }
    
    return section.numberOfObjects
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    let alumno = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    ...
    return cell
}
```